# splitting strings into columns in R

Tags: r, text, split, stringr

I have a vector with text in R data frame such as below:

`string<-c("Real estate surface: 60m2 Number of rooms: 3 Number of bedrooms: 2 Number of bathrooms: 1 Number of toilets: 0 Year of construction: 1980 Last renovation: Floor: 1/15")`

and I want to split text into 8 columns data frame with associated values, as e.g.

[image]

How can I do that?
Thanks!

Comment: Is that empty after `Last renovation`

Comment: yes. missing values

Comment: What have you tried and where do you get stuck?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An option would be to create `NA` for missing cases, then use `separate_rows/separate` to split the string

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)
library(tibble)
tibble(col = string) %>%
   mutate(col = str_replace_all(col, ": (?![0-9])", ": NA ")) %>% 
   separate_rows(col, sep="(?<=:\\s\\w{1,5}) ") %>%
   separate(col, into = c('col1', 'col2'), sep=":\\s+") %>% 
   deframe %>% 
   as.data.frame.list(check.names = FALSE) %>%
   type.convert(as.is = TRUE)
#Real estate surface Number of rooms Number of bedrooms Number of bathrooms Number of toilets Year of construction
#1             60m2               3                  2                   1                 0                 1980
#  Last renovation Floor
#1              NA  1/15
```